# The set of all permutations of indices such that the new series converges to the same limit forms a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, group-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i = s \in \mathbb{C}$ be a convergent series of complex numbers.  Then the set of all permutations $\sigma \in\operatorname{Perm}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(i)} = s$  forms a group?  Seems nontrivial to prove if it is true.

Comment: Is it a group if we allow different limits and just say it need to converges ?

Comment: That's a good question

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: There is a tangential generalization of this to permutations which preserve the convergence of *arbitrary* conditionally convergent series (but not guaranteeing that upon rearrangement the limit is the same). This can be shown to form a submonoid, but not a subgroup of $S_{\mathbb{N}}$. See these two references:

http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pjm/1102810909

 http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm69/cm69210.pdf

Comment: We clearly are not going to have that it is closed by composition. It is just tedious to write down an example. The question of preserving convergence of arbitrary convergent series is very different.

Comment: @ABC I don't think it is clear that they aren't closed under composition

Comment: @ABC: What seems particularly difficult is that we are fixing a series. There will most likely be pathalogical examples of series for which it's not a group. Are conditionally convergent examples that do form at least a semigroup?

Comment: No, not even a semigroup. This problem is very different. When you force preserving convergence of arbitrary series you cut down enormously the set of permutations. Let's take $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\ln(2)$. And consider the permutation $\sigma$ (formed in the way the standard proof of Riemann's theorem is proven) but such that the partial sums first increase to $1000$ and then they start converging to $\ln(2)$ in the best possible way. I claim that $\sigma\circ\sigma$ doesn't give you the sum $\ln(2)$ again.

Comment: @AlexR. Example 1.1 of the second paper you linked to, shows that it is not closed by inverse, for example. It shows a convergent permutation $p$, such that $p([1,n])=[1,n]$ for infinitely many $n$ (so in particular it preserves the sum of the series) but the inverse is not a convergent permutation, that means that for some series the permutation $p$ preserves the sum, but the inverse makes it diverge.

Comment: @ABC: May be I misunderstood what you meant by "best possible way", but one way we can still make it converge to $\ln 2$ is, after that initial long segment of positive terms, to take the skipped negative terms, and then continue in the original order. This has the effect that $\sigma(i)=i$ for all sufficiently large $i$. Thus the same holds for $\sigma\circ\sigma$ (and $\sigma^{-1}$), and all the permutations fixing the tail in this way surely preserve the sum.

Comment: @ABC: Thanks for the examples. I am not entirely convinced by the Example 1.1 remark, however. The definition of a convergent permutation is that it must converge for all conditionally convergent sums. In this problem, we are fixing a particular sum. Is it obvious that the example inverse permutation will fail  to be convergent for this particular permutation?

Comment: @AlexR. They construct a permutation for which $p^{-1}$ is divergent. This means there is a conditionally convergent series, for which the permutation $p^{-1}$ makes it divergent. Assume we start with *this* series. We also have that $p$ is a convergent permutation. So it turns this series into convergent, and because $p([1,n])=[1,n]$ for infinitely many $n$'s we get that it doesn't change the sum. So, for that series, the set in this question is not a group.

Comment: Of course for some convergent series the set in this question is going to be a group. For absolutely convergent series the set is all permutations and therefore it is a group. The point is that not for all convergent series it is going to be a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a reasonably simple counterexample. Let $\sigma\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the following permutation of the natural numbers:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & \cdots \\
\hline
\sigma(n) & \color{blue}2 & \color{blue}4 & \color{blue}6 & \color{red}1 & \color{blue}8 & \color{blue}{10} & \color{blue}{12} & \color{red}3 & \color{blue}{14} & \color{blue}{16} & \color{blue}{18} & \color{red}{5} & \cdots\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
with three even numbers for every odd number.  We will demonstrate a convergent series with the property that $\sigma$ does not change its value, but $\sigma^2$ does.

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence
$$
-1,2,-1,\;-\frac12,\frac22,-\frac12,\;-\frac13,\frac23,-\frac13,\;-\frac14,\frac24,-\frac14,\;\ldots
$$
and let $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence whose odd terms are zero, and whose even terms satsify $b_{2n} = a_n$.  Then the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \;=\; 0 - 1 + 0 + 2 + 0 - 1 \;+\; 0 - \frac12 + 0 + \frac22 + 0 - \frac12 + 0 \;+\; \cdots
$$
converges to $0$.  Applying the permutation $\sigma$ to the terms of this series gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \;=\; \color{blue}{-1+2-1} \color{red}{+ 0} \color{blue}{- \frac12 + \frac22 - \frac12} \color{red}{+ 0} \color{blue}{- \frac13 + \frac23 - \frac13} \color{red}{+ 0} + \cdots
$$
which also converges to $0$.  However, applying $\sigma$ again yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n \;=\; \color{blue}{2 + 0 + \frac22} \color{red}{- 1} \color{blue}{+ 0 + \frac23 + 0} \color{red}{-1} \color{blue}{+\frac24 + 0 + \frac25} \color{red}{- \frac12} + \cdots.
$$
We claim that this series does *not* converge to $0$.

To prove this, observe that the $8N$'th partial sum of this series is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{8N} d_n \;=\; 
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{3N} \frac{2}{k} \right) - \left(2\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k} \right) \;=\; 2H_{3N} - 2H_N,
$$
where $H_i$ denotes the $i$'th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  It is known that
$$
H_n \;=\; \log(n) + \gamma + o(1)
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{8N} d_n \;&=\; 2H_{3N} - 2H_N \\
\;&=\; 2\bigl(\log(3N)  + \gamma + o(1) \bigr) - 2\bigl(\log(N) + \gamma + o(1)\bigr) \\[2ex] \;&=\; \log(9) + o(1)
\end{align*}
$$
Since the terms of the series converge to zero, it follows that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n \;=\; \log(9).
$$

**Edit:**
By the way, I should mention how I made this example up.  Suppose we are given a permutation $\sigma$ and a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n$ with the following properties:

1. The distance $|\sigma(n) - n|$ that $\sigma$ moves terms is unbounded.
2. The series is conditionally convergent.

Under these conditions, $\sigma$ will almost always change the value of the sum (or change the convergent series to a divergent one).

So all I did was pick the simplest permutation $\sigma$ that I could think of, and then I created a conditionally convergent series with $0$'s in the right places to be unchanged by $\sigma$.

Under these conditions, it will usually be the case that $\sigma^2$ changes the value of the sum.  The only hard part is making sure that the original series converges, and that the original sum and the final sum can be evaluated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the weaker question.  What structure do such transformations form when $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(i)}$ simply has to converge?

The set of all sequences $(a_i)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(i)}$ converges forms a vector space.  Proof, let $\lambda$ be a scalar and $a, b$ be two sequences with this property, each of whose series converge under $\sigma$ to $s$ and $t$ respectively.  Then for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ we have for finite $N$
$$
| \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\lambda a_{\sigma(i)} + b_{\sigma(i)}) - \lambda s + t| \leq \lambda|\sum_{i=1}^N a_{\sigma(i)} - s| + |\sum_{i=1}^{N} b_{\sigma(i)} - t|
$$

The right side can be made as small as we want for sufficiently large $N$ so we do indeed have a vector space.

Let the vector space induced by the index permutation $\sigma$ be called $V_{\sigma}$.  Another index permutation $\pi$ can be decomposed into a possibly infinite sequence of transpositions $\pi = \tau_1 \circ \tau_2 \circ \dots$  (Proof?)

So if $(a_i) \in V_\sigma$, then $(a_{\tau_1(i)}) \in V_{\sigma}$ since $(a_{\tau_1(i)}) = (a_i) + (0,\dots, a_{\tau_1(i)} - a_i, \dots, a_i - a_{\tau_1(i)}, \dots, 0)$, the second term being absolutely convergent and so clearly in $V_{\sigma}. \ $  Similarly $(a_{\tau_1\cdot\tau_2(i)}) \in V_{\sigma}$, and so on...

If $V_{\sigma}$ is closed, then it contains all its limit points.  Assuming it's closed...

I give up.  Too many assumptions without proof.

Comment: I believe this is related to the Levy Steinitz theorem.

Comment: My last comment above shows that it is not going to be a group. I would bet it is not going to be even a semigroup, but for the moment you can change the question to ask if it could be a semigroup.

Comment: @ABC asking if it could be a semigroup is equivalent to asking if it is a monoid as the trivial permutation is surely the identity

Comment: And furthermore in what topology it shall be closed ?